# Trouble with formula in excel

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I have two excel sheets (eg: Sheet1 and Shee2), with the formula below in cell A1 in Sheet1:

```
=if(istext(search("Yes", 'Sheet2'!A1),"TRUE", "FALSE")
```

This code will search for value "Yes" in Sheet2 in cell A1 and will write TRUE or FALSE in Sheet1,A1 depending on whether the value "Yes" is present or not.

The issue I am having is that I want the formula to not only search A1 but A1 to A3 in Sheet2 and if any two cells contains value "Yes" then the formula should return "TRUE", else "FALSE".

I tried this :

```
=if(istext(search("Yes", 'Sheet2'!A1:A3),"TRUE", "FALSE")
```

but this formula returns "TURE" if any one of the cell from A1 to A3 contains value "Yes".

I would appreciate your help regarding the same.

Thanks much!!

Comment: Where is the closing parenthesis for the `istext` function supposed to be?  You have three open parens but only two closing parens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Sheet2'!A1:A3,"*Yes*")>=2,"TRUE", "FALSE")
```